# Why can't Amazon Redshift Parse this Valid JSON string?

Tags: json, amazon-redshift

I'm using Amazon Redshift's JSON parsing abilities. Most of the time it works, but it fails in this case. I'm getting the following error:

```
error:  JSON parsing error
  code:      8001
  context:   invalid json object {"collection_id": 12, "activity_name": "Hour of Zen: The \"Dead Sea\" Float"}
```

I was under the impression that the backslash was the proper escape for the double quote (and this was automatically generated by Python's JSON package).

Comment: According to this (http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) you're good. Maybe a bug on their end?

Comment: I just ran into the same exact problem.  It seems to be specific to escaped double quotes, but I haven't been able to figure out any more information yet.

Comment: any other solution here than replace?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, per [this Redshift forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=158796&tstart=0) this is a know bug, but there is no ETA for a fix. The forum recommends this workaround:

Replace:

```
json_extract_path_text(event_properties,'someValue')
```

with

```
json_extract_path_text(regexp_replace(event_properties,'\\\\.',''),'someValue')
```

Comment: sorry can you explain why '\\\\.' works? Why does that replace the single slash with nothing?

Answer (score 1):

If you use json_extract_path_text(event_properties,'someValue', TRUE) it will return null instead of throwing an error.